# Fail to change password of mysql on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, passwords

I want to change the password of mysql on my Mac. I believe I never changed it before. Both the user and password are root, and I have no problem accessing it.

However, when I follow instructions I found online, typing the command below:
`/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password [my new password]`

then I typed '`root`' to the password it requires.

I got this response:
"`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`"

I tried to solve it with method I found:

1. stop MYSQL:`# /etc/init.d/mysql stop` or`# stop mysql` or `#service mysql stop`
2. type this: `# mysql_safe --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`
3. login MYSQL: `#mysql -uroot mysql` or `# mysql -uroot mysql -p` 
   then enter root password and enter MYSQL
4. reset root password: `mysql>UPDATE user SET Password=[new password] where USER = "root";`

And there are couple more steps which I didn't test. Because it didn't work from the first step. This made me think that may be it's not the correct way to solve my problem.

I've been looking for answers for couple hours already, and could only try to ask for solution now. Please give me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

In your method (step 2) you didn't include the correct user:

```
--user=root
```

It should be `root`, although it's currently specifying `mysql`.

Comment: thank you for the correction.
the thing is, even I type `#stop mysql` or the other two, the command line didn't show anything back!

Comment: @SamuelLin: You need to **stop servers** in MAMP, kill it's MySQL process, or trying stopping the service using the absolute MAMP path; (the first way is likely the most simple) — and quit MAMP.  The commands should use the MAMP path (eg. `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe`, etc.).

Comment: I've stop servers by clicking the stop servers button on MAMP, and type exactly `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_safe` or `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_safe --user=root mysql --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`
but it response:`No such file or directory`
I'm new to this, sorry about these details of my questions.

Comment: Try using a period in front of the first `/` of the path, or cd into it (eg. `./Applications/MAMP/...`).

Comment: thank you for the response, I've tried it. Still didn't work.

Comment: I just found a simple way to change my password of mysql db through phpmyadmin panel.
Anyway, thank you, for your help.